# How to remove specific url parameter in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this url pattern

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?
addressLine={0}&
adminDistrict={1}&
locality={2}&
countryRegion={3}&
postalCode={4}&
userLocation={5}&
inclnb=1&
key={6}
```

Let us say that `locality` and `userLocation` have no values

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?
addressLine=Main&
adminDistrict=WA&
locality=&
countryRegion=US&
postalCode=98001&
userLocation=&
inclnb=1&
key=BingKey
```

Then I want to remove all parameters that is equal to "`&`"
Like for example: '`locality=&`' and '`userLocation=&`'

And should be look like this:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?
addressLine=Main&
adminDistrict=WA&
countryRegion=US&
postalCode=98001&
inclnb=1&
key=BingKey
```

Final Output:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine=Main&adminDistrict=WA&countryRegion=US&postalCode=98001&inclnb=1&key=BingKey
```

Comment: Who's to say they are _in order_?

Comment: What do you mean? I know that this is possible in regex. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Who's to say that the parameters are in _that_ order? You really should be using a URL parser.

Comment: Are you building the URL yourself or do you not have any control over it?

Comment: @DGibbs I'm building the url myself. My first plan is to combine parameters that has values. But it makes a lot of code and I think of regex. But thanks to Willen Duncan suggestion, I got the idea now.

Comment: @fiberOptics In that case do a `!string.IsNullOrEmpty` check on each of the parameters before adding them to the URL and skip a regex.

Comment: @DGibbs Thank you. I got your point :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you specificly want to use regular expressions? There are some classes in C# specificly build for building and handling URIs. I suggest you look at [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) or [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx).

You would then parse the query string, loop through the variables that have only a key and no value, and reconstruct a new uri without them. It will be much easier to read and maintain than a regular expression.

---

**Edit**: I quickly decided to see how this could be done:

```
string originalUri = "http://www.example.org/etc?query=string&query2=&query3=";

// Create the URI builder object which will give us access to the query string.
var uri = new UriBuilder(originalUri);

// Parse the querystring into parts
var query = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

// Loop through the parts to select only the ones where the value is not null or empty  
var resultQuery = query.AllKeys
                       .Where(k => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(query[k]))
                       .Select(k => string.Format("{0}={1}", k, query[k]));

// Set the querystring part to the parsed version with blank values removed
uri.Query = string.Join("&",resultQuery);

// Done, uri now contains "http://www.example.org/etc?query=string"
```

Answer (score 2):

@"[\w]+=\&" should get you what you are looking for, but wouldn't it be easier to simply not add the parameter to the url string if the corresponding value is empty?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I like your suggestion but I think Willem answer is the right way to do. +1